# use array to pass as a parameter to a function in helper, in side {{#each}} for same array(handlebars)

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js

I am trying to use {{#each}} in email templates. I want to use the same array to pass as a parameter to helper function, to do some stuff. I am unable to get the value of the array inside the loop.

Here is my code that I am using.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifSameCbeprev', function(index, msg, options) { 
 var ind = parseInt(index);
 var x = ind - 1 ;
    console.log(msg); //here value is undefined.
 if(x<0)
 {  
  return options.inverse(this);
 }
 else
 {
  console.log(msg);
  if(msg[ind].cbe === msg[x].cbe)
  {   
   return options.fn(this);
  }
  else
  {   
   return options.inverse(this);
  }
 }

  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    {{#each msg}}
        <!-- If task is created  -->
        {{#iftytask ty}}
        <tr width="100%" height="auto" style=" min-height:40px;">
        <td width="100%" height="100%">
       <table width="100%" height="auto" style="padding:10px;">
         <tr width="100%" height="auto"style="position:relative;">
             <td width="98%" height="100%" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;">
                  {{#ifSameCbeprev @index ../msg}}

                   {{else}}
                       <span>{{cfna}}</span>
                {{/ifSameCbeprev}}
              </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </body>
  </html>
```

The code i am using is as above. 
../msg is giving undefined(i.e. msg in ifSameCbeprev). I tried using 'this', msg and ../../msg as well in place of ../msg. But always I am getting undefined inside the function ifSameCbeprev.
Any idea how to use the array inside the {{#each}}? 
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: I don't know nothing about `handlebars.js` but you sure you need to use `#ifSameCbeprev` instead of `#if SameCbeprev`?

Comment: @VitorCanova yes. that is user defined helper function, that i have created.

Comment: Hum. Nice. And you sure it is returning something? Have you tried return a hard coded value? Or you sure it's a problem with `@index`?

Comment: Problem is not with '@index'. Problem is passing 'msg' as parameter, (i.e. to ifSameCbeprev I am passing '@index', which will give the current index and msg, which is the array that I am using to loop through ). I am not getting any way to access the 'msg' inside the 'msg' itself. @VitorCanova

Comment: If I won't pass the parameter properly, the function won't give any output. Since msg will be undefined inside the function. @VitorCanova

Comment: Well, so I can't help. Will upvote maybe someone else know this framework. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried doing in this way instead of checking in the html. This solved my problem. Giving the code below.

```js
var msgs = [{cbe : 'abc', ty : 'task'}, {cbe : 'abcd', ty : 'task'}];

for(var k in msgs)
  {
    if(k != 0)
        {
          var sameSender = getCFna(msgs[k-1].cbe , msgs[k].cbe);
    
    if(sameSender == "same")
    {
        msgs[k].creatorName = "";
    }
    else
    {
        msgs[k].creatorName = msgs[k].cfna ? msgs[k].cfna : msgs[k].cbe;
    }
    
    console.log(msgs[k].creatorName);
        }
  }

function getCFna(prevem , currentEm)
{
    if(prevem.toLowerCase().trim() == currentEm.toLowerCase().trim())
    {
        return "same";
    }
    else
    {
        return "not same";
    }
};
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    {{#each msg}}
        <!-- If task is created  -->
        {{#iftytask ty}}
        <tr width="100%" height="auto" style=" min-height:40px;">
        <td width="100%" height="100%">
       <table width="100%" height="auto" style="padding:10px;">
         <tr width="100%" height="auto"style="position:relative;">
             <td width="98%" height="100%" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;">
                       <span>{{creatorName}}</span>
              </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </body>
  </html>
```

If any other solution is there can post also.